# Simplify PowerShell Script with Replace Statements

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run this script on a 50GB file in Windows 2012 R2 and I would like to hopefully get the three replace statements into one pass rather than three. Also, it is important that the replaces occur in that order. Any suggestions to simplify this and make it run efficiently would be greatly appreciated!

```
$filePath = "D:\FileLocation\file_name.csv"
(Get-Content $filePath | out-string).Replace('"', '""') | Set-Content $filePath
(Get-Content $filePath | out-string).Replace('|~|', '"') | Set-Content $filePath
(Get-Content $filePath | out-string).Replace('|@|', ',') | Set-Content $filePath
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With such a large file, I suggest you process the file line by line (or in batches) which should speed up the entire process.

You can copy the Script mentioned by True here http://community.idera.com/powershell/ask_the_experts/f/learn_powershell-12/18821/how-to-remove-specific-rows-from-csv-files-in-powershell

but instead of writing $Line straight away, performing you replaces

```
$sw.WriteLine($line.replace().replace().replace())
```

Be careful with get-content since that will try to load the entire file and becomes very slow once you are out of memory.
Also be careful if you don't have much disk space. The linked solution will make a copy of the file (with the changes) before replacing it.

Comment: Thank you so much, that is perfect! I was running into a memory issue as well.

Comment: The [`Get-Content`](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-5.1) has a `-ReadCount` parameter which specifies how many lines of content are sent through the pipeline at a time. *"this parameter does not change the content displayed, but it does affect the time it takes to display the content. As the value of ReadCount increases, the time it takes to return the first line increases, but the total time for the operation decreases. This can make a perceptible difference in very large items."*. Anyways, streaming is still faster...

Comment: @Shadowzee Do you know how you would adjust that code to do it in batches rather than a single line at a time?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't recall anymore. I was working on parsing a 6GB file and ran into performance issues. The main thing I remember was the reading in Batches is faster than reading line by line, only by a little, but it's a bit more complicated since you have to manage how you read and write the batch of lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can use -replace operator

```
$filepath="c:\temp\text.txt"
(Get-Content $filepath) -replace 'test','1' -replace 'text','2' -replace '123','3' |Set-Content $filepath
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the .replace() in the same line.

```
$filepath="/Users/me/Desktop/text.txt"
'test text 123' |Out-File -Path $filepath
(Get-Content $filepath|Out-String).Replace('test','1').Replace('text','2').Replace('123','3')|Set-Content $filepath
Get-Content $filepath
1 2 3
```